# Tab order in react components?

Tags: reactjs, tab-ordering, react-ref

I have a [Code Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-sky-dkjwd) that demonstrates what I want to do.

When the user presses a button, a text input is revealed and is given focus.

To do this, I use a ref and give it focus, which is fine:

```
  //When user clicks button, show input
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setShowInput(true);
  }, []);  

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showInput && inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [showInput]);
```

When the user *tabs* out of the text field, I want the focus to be back on that button.

In the code I have here, I achieve this also by using a  ref and giving focus to the button.

```
  //When user exits input, unshow input
  //Also, need to tab to button if it was a tab button press. 
  const handleInputBlur = useCallback(() => {
    setShowInput(false);
    if (buttonRef.current) {
      buttonRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, []);
```

However, the problem is if the user instead *uses their mouse* to click say, the other button, then focus is still given to the trigger button.

What I'd like to be able to do is define some tab order for these components, that would be:

TextField => Trigger Button => Other Button

However, I don't want to hard code tab indexes into my component, as that would likely not play well with the application as a whole?

Is there an elegant react solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe there is another way to control your tab order apart from using the ```tabIndex``` prop or handling focus manually with refs as you are.  That said, I have to wonder if trying to take control of the tab order in this way is the best idea, as it's contrary to the natural flow of the elements.  If someone executes a click/tab that they would expect to take them further down the page and focus moves in the opposite direction, it might be confusing.  Shift + Tab exists specifically to allow users to navigate backwards if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer here is that if you want your tab order to be TextField => Trigger Button => Other Button, then have the HTML render in that order.

You can then use CSS to change the visual ordering.

```css
.container {
 display: flex; 
 border: solid 1px black; 
}

 button {
 margin: 1em; 
 padding: 1em; 
 }  
 
 .order-1 {
    order: 1; 
 }
  
 .order-2 {
    order: 2; 
 } 
 
 .order-3 {
    order: 3; 
 }
 
 .order-4 {
    order: 4; 
 }
```

```html
<div class = "container"> 
  <button class ="order-4"> 1</button> 
  <button class = "order-2"> 2</button> 
  <button class = "order-3"> 3</button> 
  <button class ="order-1"> 4</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked the simplicity of dwjohnston's answer. If anything more complex is required we can consider the [react-tabindex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tabindex) plugin.

> useTabIndex returns a value to pass to the tabIndex prop on elements
> of your choosing. If wrapped in an active  ancestor, that
> tabIndex value will automatically be set to -1, making the elements
> untabbable.

```
$ npm install react-tabindex

import { useTabIndex } from 'react-tabindex';
 
function ExampleButton() {
  const tabIndex = useTabIndex();
 
  return <button tabIndex={tabIndex}>Click here!</button>;
}
```